# Guide me regarding WSP language

Tags: sharepoint-2007

How can I make language(Danish 1030) specific wsp files.

I created 4 sites manually on my system. Now my client want solution in WSP files. Thus I choose SharePoint Solution Generator to generate wsp files.

Now I am using Visual studio to deploy solution to get wsp file. Is there any setting regarding language in this step.

Ultimately I want wsp files to give to my client deployable in Danish (1030).

I am not using WSPBuilder because I need the whole site, which I did n't built programmatically. If you know anyway that we can build wsp with the help of WSPBuilder by using site (which is created manually) please let me know.

I have Language pack of Danish installed and it is running properly

Answer (score 0):

So to create a WSP package I have always used the WSPBuilder but to my knowledge the only thing that you need to do to create a specific language edition is to put your language specific files in the 12/Template/Layouts/1030 folder.